# Is function differentiation an automorphism on continious function space?

Tags: integration, derivatives, linear-transformations, function-spaces

I’m looking for examples of automorphisms. I came up with a curious one, but I don’t know if it is correct:

Let $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ be the space of smooth complex functions $\tau:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined over the domain $\Omega$, and $f\in\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$. Define the linear endomorphism $T:\mathbb{C}^{\infty}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ as:
$$T(f)=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z}=g(t)\quad \{z;t\}\in \Omega$$
Define $T^{-1}:\mathbb{C}^{\infty}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ to be:
$$T^{-1}(g)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}g(t)\mathrm{d}t=f(z)$$
Since:
$$T\circ T^{-1}(f)=f$$
Then, $T$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Differentiation isn't injective. Integration with fixed endpoints is only a right inverse, not a left inverse.